# How to receive image file from rest client

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am getting a request from mobile to my application, mobile technologies are android/iPhone.

I am using `JSON + restful` web service + `spring` + `hibernate`. I have to receive an image from mobile and saving to `Oracle DB`. again I have to get the image from DB and send back to mobile.

I am new to this environment. Please give some code level idea to implement it.

Comment: Make an http post request to your web-server along with the file.

Comment: What will be the file datatype i have to take.

Comment: You need to use Multipart Files in spring and it would be a class.

Comment: please help me through code level if possible

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a form in html which mobile phones would navigate and use it to upload the file and sent it to server.

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="uploadForm">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br />
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

In your application context file declare following `bean`.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Your `controller` would look like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm")FileUploadForm uploadFiles) {
  //explore uploadFiles for further assessment
  return "Success";
}
```

Hope this helps.